# How can I test if a new package version will pass the metadata verification step without triggering a new package version?

Tags: apex, managed-package

All of the following corresponds to Apex code.

I'm creating a new package via the 2GP process. The package is pretty basic. It has a few custom objects and a couple flexipages. I've been struggling with the flexipages and getting the metadata correct. I only find out that the metadata is incorrect when I create a new package version. The downside to this approach is that it takes longer than it should, since more steps are being triggered than I need, and it costs one of my package version creates. I'm limited to six new package versions per day. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong because now that I've hit my daily limit, I'm unable to test if the changes I made to the flexipage will pass the metadata verification step.

How can I check if my new changes will pass the metadata verification step, without triggering a new package version create request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have looked more closely into the `sfdx` commands. The command `sfdx project:deploy:validate` was exactly what I was looking for. I'll make sure I run this command to check if the metadata is valid before creating a new package version.